# I have some trouble with my Java code. It won't run when telling the difference between positive and negative number when in a loop

Tags: java, loops, debugging, if-statement

### Problem to solve

- Write a program called MyWhiley1 that asks the user to type a
  positive integer.
- When the user types a negative value the program writes ERROR and
  asks for another value.
- When the user types 0 that means that the last value has been typed
  and the program must write the average of the positive integers.
- If the number of typed values is zero the program writes 'NO
  AVERAGE'.

But I have some errors my code does not run properly if I type a positive number and then a negative number nothing happens.

```
public class MyWhiley1 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int sum = 0, list = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a postive integer if you enter zero the list is compelete");
        int number = reader.nextInt();
        do {
            if (number > 0) {
                sum += number;
                list++;
            } else if (number < 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR type in a postive integer");

            }
            reader.close();
        } while (number != 0);

        if (list != 0) {
            System.out.println("Average is: " + sum / list);
        } else
            System.out.println("NO average");
    }
}
```

Comment: You never read another number inside the loop. Change `reader.close();`, (By the way, you shouldn't close a `Scanner` reading from `System.in`!) to `number=reader.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues, you are not reading the number within loop and you are closing the reader while being within loop:

```
int number = 0;

do
{
    number = reader.nextInt();

    if (number>0)
    {
        sum+=number;
        list++;
    }
    else if (number<0)  
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR type in a postive integer");

    }

}while (number!=0);
reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening here is that you accidentally put the `reader.close()` call inside the while-loop, so the Scanner is closed after the first iteration of the loop, regardless of what happens. Try putting `reader.close` immediately after the end of the while-loop; that should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your input and I just tried it out and it still wont work. I get this input back it won't  move forward.                         
Type a postive integer if you enter zero the list is compelete
1
2
3
-3
0